# How can I return a result set of records with duplicate columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database table in which each row has a `first_name` and `last_name` column, like so:

```
 id   first_name   last_name
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | ted        | jones     |
| 2  | mike       | johnson   |
| 3  | ted        | jones     |
| 4  | jan        | smith     |
| 5  | anna       | white     |
| 6  | jan        | smith     |
|-----------------------------|
```

I want to find all records that are duplicates, i.e., the first and last names are identical. Given the data above, I want a result set like:

```
 id   first_name   last_name
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | ted        | jones     |
| 3  | ted        | jones     |
| 4  | jan        | smith     |
| 6  | jan        | smith     |
|----|------------|-----------|
```

(More specifically, I'd like to get a count of such duplicate records, e.g., `2` [or `4`, either would suffice] in this case.)

Is there a way to do this via SQL?

Comment: yes - use the HAVING COUNT clause

Comment: Lots of ways.  Which db server are you actually using?

Comment: @ChrisLively: Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way of finding duplicates is:

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*) as DupeCount 
from table
group by first_name, last_name
having count(*) > 1
```

This will get you all the names.  There are multiple ways of getting the associated Ids, but some of the better ones are server specific.

Answer (score 2):

You join the table with itself and mismatch on id (PK)

Assuming ur table name is **Names**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) CNT, N1.first_name,N1.last_name
  FROM NAMES N1 INNER JOIN 
       NAMES N2 ON
       N1.first_name = N2.first_name
       AND N1.last_name = N2.last_name
       AND N1.ID <> N2.ID
 GROUP BY N1.first_name,N1.last_name
```

Comment: That gets interesting counts.  If there are 3 rows with the same name and different numbers, you get a count of 6, don't you?

Comment: Yep you are right, they will be cross-joined

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Number of duplicates" FROM `tableName` GROUP BY first_name, last_name;
```

To get a total sum, an easy way would be to wrap that up with a SUM() again, or using a HAVING ... construct, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> My solution is

```
 select t.id, t.first_name,t.last_name
 from TableTest t
 where first_name in
(
  select t1.first_name
  from TableTest t1
  group by t1.first_name,t1.last_name
  having count(*) > 1
) 
and last_name in
(
  select t1.last_name
  from TableTest t1
  group by t1.first_name,t1.last_name
  having count(*) > 1
)
```